# Automatic Investment Plan - Non U.S resident

Tags: mutual-funds, broker, europe

I am looking for any options to invest small amounts each month/quarter without commissions eating me up.

As a U.S. resident and investing in a Mutual Fund, this is no problem. AIP programs
Non U.S. residents (like me), are not allowed to invest in Mutual Funds at least directly without a broker account (the ones that allow this require minimum capital of 100 k)

My "work around" this far was to open a broker account, 1. bank transfer commissions 2. convert currency in dollars (forex commissions) 3. buy an ETF (commissions again)

Are there any publicly traded Mutual Funds?
Is there any way to invest small amounts frequently without so many commissions?

I am E.U. resident if this helps.

Comment: Did you check what brokers in your country provide access to the US market and what their terms are?

Comment: Please tag this with a specific country trash. It's surprising hours many Europeans think the rules are similar regardless of which country they live in.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what the real question is...

Answer (score -2):

Are there any non publicly traded mutual funds? and why do you want to invest direct in the USA you know you will have to deal with the IRS as well as your own tax body?

One solution would be to invest in shares in investment companies (investment trusts)either in the USA or in the Eu

Comment: why do you want to invest direct in the USA? In my country 'SEC' is pretty lose and i do not trust earning reports from companies etc. There was a big crush 10+ years ago and never recovered. Why not in a E.U. etf? well as amateur investor i have more trust to U.S. market return wise in the long term

Comment: i was very concerned about double taxation, but i have been told that capital gains are taxed at the source i.e. U.S., hopefully this is true:D

Comment: @blended this is not true.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that there are no publicly traded mutual funds, or that investment trusts and mutual funds are not one and the same...

Comment: @littleadv What you would recommend then? An investment fund in E.U.?

Comment: @blended why not?

Comment: @blended you will get double taxed on dividends unless you fill out a w8ben e and I believe you country has to have a tax treaty with the usa

Comment: @littleadv actually they quite different closed vs open ended and an IT has an democratic AGM which investors can goto and ask Questions

Comment: @Pepone investment trust and mutual fund are different names for the same thing. IT is the UK term, MF is the US term, but essentially they mean the same things. Open-ended/close-ended, good customer support or not - that's not what defines whether it is an investment trust or not.

Comment: @littleadv ok so send me the paper work for a US mutual Funds AGM most of them are not investment companies

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "most of them are not investment companies." How are you defining "investment company"?